# Customise Kivy settings panel by redefining style.kv

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am using the default Kivy Settings widget to create a settings screen for my app. I don't want to build a custom settings widget from scratch, but I would like to customise simple properties like the text size of each item and the colour of the "close" button.

Based on the Kivy [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#redefining-a-widget-s-style) and the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812576/how-to-customize-style-kv-in-kivy) I understand that I need to modify the styles for the different Settings class widgets that are defined in `style.kv`. For example, I have been able to add the following to the top of my `main.py` to redefine the style of the `MenuSidebar` widget and change the size and colour of the settings "close" button:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<-MenuSidebar>:
    size_hint_x: None
    width: '200dp'
    buttons_layout: menu
    close_button: button
    GridLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        cols: 1
        id: menu
        padding: 5

        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgb: .2, .2, .2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.right - 1, self.y
                size: 1, self.height

    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        id: button
        size_hint: None, None
        width: root.width - dp(20)
        height: max(50, self.texture_size[1] + dp(20))
        pos: root.x + dp(10), root.y + dp(10)
        font_size: '30sp'
```

[image]

Following a similar approach, I now want to modify the style of each setting item so that the text colour is red. I add the following into `Builder.load_string()` at the top of my `main.py` to redefine the style of the `SettingItem` widget:

```
<-SettingItem>:
    size_hint: .25, None
    height: labellayout.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
    content: content
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 47 / 255., 167 / 255., 212 / 255., self.selected_alpha
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.y + 1
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgb: .2, .2, .2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.y - 2
            size: self.width, 1

    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos

        Label:
            size_hint_x: .66
            id: labellayout
            markup: True
            text: u'{0}\\n[size=13sp][color=999999]{1}[/color][/size]'.format(root.title or '', root.desc or '')
            font_size: '15sp'
            color: [1, 0 , 0 , 1]
            text_size: self.width - 32, None

        BoxLayout:
            id: content
            size_hint_x: .33
```

Everything works as expected, however the value of each setting item disappears.

[image]

I have tried everything I can think off, but I can't work out how to modify the appearance of the settings screen without losing the actual value of each setting item, or messing up the whole layout of the settings screen. Can anyone advise how I can achieve my goal?

Here is a minimal reproducible example illustrating the issue that is based on the Kivy Settings [example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/settings/main.py)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Configure app (or press F1)'
        on_release: app.open_settings()
    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'Hello'

<-MenuSidebar>:
    size_hint_x: None
    width: '200dp'
    buttons_layout: menu
    close_button: button
    GridLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        cols: 1
        id: menu
        padding: 5

        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgb: .2, .2, .2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.right - 1, self.y
                size: 1, self.height

    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        id: button
        size_hint: None, None
        width: root.width - dp(20)
        height: max(50, self.texture_size[1] + dp(20))
        pos: root.x + dp(10), root.y + dp(10)
        font_size: '30sp'
        color: [1, 0 , 0, 1]

<-SettingItem>:
    size_hint: .25, None
    height: labellayout.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
    content: content
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 47 / 255., 167 / 255., 212 / 255., self.selected_alpha
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.y + 1
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgb: .2, .2, .2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.y - 2
            size: self.width, 1

    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos

        Label:
            size_hint_x: .66
            id: labellayout
            markup: True
            text: u'{0}\\n[size=13sp][color=999999]{1}[/color][/size]'.format(root.title or '', root.desc or '')
            font_size: '15sp'
            color: [1, 0 , 0 , 1]
            text_size: self.width - 32, None

        BoxLayout:
            id: content
            size_hint_x: .33

'''

json = '''
[
    {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Label caption",
        "desc": "Choose the text that appears in the label",
        "section": "My Label",
        "key": "text"
    },
    {
        "type": "numeric",
        "title": "Label font size",
        "desc": "Choose the font size the label",
        "section": "My Label",
        "key": "font_size"
    }
]
'''


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        label = root.ids.label
        label.text = self.config.get('My Label', 'text')
        label.font_size = float(self.config.get('My Label', 'font_size'))
        return root

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('My Label', {'text': 'Hello', 'font_size': 20})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('My Label', self.config, data=json)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        Logger.info("main.py: App.on_config_change: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(
            config, section, key, value))

        if section == "My Label":
            if key == "text":
                self.root.ids.label.text = value
            elif key == 'font_size':
                self.root.ids.label.font_size = float(value)

    def close_settings(self, settings=None):
        Logger.info("main.py: App.close_settings: {0}".format(settings))
        super(MyApp, self).close_settings(settings)


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example to the original question based on the Kivy Settings [example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/settings/main.py)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe you should report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your kv string:

```
<SettingString>:
    Label:
        text: root.value or ''
        pos: root.pos
        font_size: '15sp'    
        color: 1,0,0,1
```

Color obviously can be whatever you want.
this only works for the settings string, if you use other settings objects modify them in a similar way :)

Comment: Thanks! That cracked it. Not sure why I didn't think of doing this in the first place...